# Overriding the view of a DataGrid scrollbar

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, custom-controls

I am trying to customize the look of a scrollbar inside a xaml datagrid. I can create the usercontrol for the style with no problems, but if I wrap it around the datagrid that doesnt work. Is there something I can bind to within the DataGrid properties that would use the custom control or style?

Thanks SO

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to make your custom ScrollBar control template. Then you can open a copy of the DataGrid control template in Expression Blend, find the existing scrollbar control it's using and apply your style to it then save it in a resourced dictionary using the BasedOn value to the TargetType. This is recommended or if its an adhoc solution, you can apply it to the usercontrol.resources of your datagrid.

You can find the scrollbar control template [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742173%28VS.85%29.aspx)